# Prove that the sequence $x_n=n$ is Cauchy for the metric $d(x,y)=\frac{\vert x-y \vert}{\sqrt {1+x^2} \sqrt{1+y^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could you please prove that the sequence $x_n=n$ is Cauchy for the metric $d(x,y)=\frac{\vert x-y \vert}{\sqrt {1+x^2} \sqrt{1+y^2}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose $m > n $, then

$$ d(x_m,x_n) = \frac{ |m-n|}{\sqrt{1+n^2} \sqrt{1+m^2}} \leq\frac{|m-n|}{nm} < \frac{|m-n|}{n^2}$$

and you can make RHS as small as you want.

Answer (score 6):

$$d(n,n+1)\leqslant\frac1{n^2}\ \text{and}\ \sum_n\frac1{n^2}\ \text{converges}$$